# Bootstrap Scrollspy - Last navigation item don't open up right position

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Problem is simple, i made website using bootstrap scrollspy. I have 4 nav items on fixed navbar. All are showing up in right position if i click on them, except the last one. I tried adding one more item, but always the fourth one is having a problem. If i scroll to item it shows correctly on navbar active.

```
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#section1">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section2">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section3">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section4">4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="section1">
        <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>1</h1>
            <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="section2">
        <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>2</h1>
            <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="section3">
        <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>3</h1>
            <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="section4">
        <div class="starter-template">
            <h1>4</h1>
            <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var offset = 60;

$('.navbar li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
    scrollBy(0, -offset);
});
    </script>
    </body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin-top: 60px;
    position: relative;
}
#section1, #section2, #section3, #section4 {
    padding-top:60px;
    height:500px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1e88e5;
}
```

```js
var offset = 60;

$('.navbar li a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $($(this).attr('href'))[0].scrollIntoView();
  scrollBy(0, -offset);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
}
#section1,
#section2,
#section3,
#section4 {
  padding-top: 60px;
  height: 500px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1e88e5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>

      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#section2">2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#section3">3</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#section4">4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="section1">
    <div class="starter-template">
      <h1>1</h1>

      <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
        <br>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="section2">
    <div class="starter-template">
      <h1>2</h1>

      <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
        <br>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="section3">
    <div class="starter-template">
      <h1>3</h1>

      <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
        <br>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="section4">
    <div class="starter-template">
      <h1>4</h1>

      <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.
        <br>All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @hunter-turner Okay I found out that last script did that. I removed it, but it gets back to my older problem, that if i click item then it shows +60px more above than item starts.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. If you remove the margin-top you have for your body, It should fix that problem. Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/m8btj1cu/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your javascript isn't functioning properly. Instead, of using the offset, you could just add padding to the section container.

```
#section1, #section2, #section3, #section4 {
    height:500px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1e88e5;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

And to fix the height issue when you first load it, just remove the margin-top you have for your body css.

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
```

Here is a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hunter377/m8btj1cu/8/)**

Comment: It did fix only the first body div problem, but i guess its pretty cool anyway that it adds +60px to each div. With padding i can make it like its meant to be like this